# Creating custom jQuery function without selector prerequisite

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that I can create custom jQuery plugins by using the `$.fn.myFunction` constructor, and the calling the custom function in JavaScript as `$('selector').myFunction()`.

However, for a project I'm currently working on, I need to be able to define a function that does not require a selector to work.This is actually for a MessageBox plugin, which will act in a similar manner to C#'s `MessageBox` class. As such, I would ideally like to create the function as `MessageBox`, and then call it as follows:

`var myMessage = $.MessageBox();` and then in turn `myMessage.Show();`

Notice the lack of selector brakets in the jQuery reference at the beginning of the function call.

Any advice on the best practice for this would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work:

```
jQuery.MessageBox = function() {
  var show = function() {
    // something...
  }
  var hide = function() {
    // something...
  }
  return {
    show: show,
    hide: hide
  }
}
```

Comment: @relipse: Can you clarify why you have doubts?

Comment: Because I'm wondering if messing the jquery's namespace like that is good practice, or there is another way. In the meantime I have implemented my own dialogBox which does not use a selector that is similar to your code above. https://github.com/relipse/jquery-dialogPrompt I know the YAHOO! library has a special YAHOO.namespace() function to declare your own.

Answer (score 5):

[relipse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993494/relipse) has a good point - as you are cluttering the main namespace. A solution if you have more objects than just eg. MessageBox is to create your own namespace like this:

```
jQuery.myLib = {
  MessageBox: function() {
    var show = function() {
      // something...
    }
    var hide = function() {
      // something...
    }
    return {
      show: show,
      hide: hide
    }
  }
}
```

That means you are only taking one place in the main namespace (the name of your library, in this case `myLib`). You'd call it like this:

```
jQuery.myLib.MessageBox.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function ($) {
    $.MessageBox = function () {
        var show = function () {
            // something...
        }
        var hide = function () {
            // something...
        }
        return {
            show: show,
            hide: hide
        }
    }
})(Jquery);
```

I think you better scope to Immediate invocation function to avoid collision with namespaces.