# jQuery plugin, with or without a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a nice jQuery plugin that looks something like this:

```
  ;(function($, window, document){

  // MyPlugin stuff

  $.fn.myPlugin = function(){

      new MyPlugin(this).init();

  }

  )(jQuery, window, document);
```

Works great when called on an element like this: `$('.something').myPlugin();` but I'd like to also be able to do this `$.myPlugin.somemethod()` (use it without an jQuery selector).

How would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to do it? If so, what have you tried? Here is a post that nearly duplicates your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764217/creating-custom-jquery-function-without-selector-prerequisite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By not attaching it to jQuery's prototype (fn), but as a property of `jQuery` instead, or in addition to the plugin etc :

```
$.myPlugin = {
    somemethod : function() {
        alert('stuff');
    }
}
```

Comment: So I would have to add this in addition to the $.fn... so that I could use it both ways?

Comment: @nick in fact yes, but if you need those 2 way for the exact same thing, there is something wrong.

Comment: I don't need them for the same thing. I want to be able call the plugin on an element but I'd also like to be able to invoke it manually, passing in the options (that would otherwise be in the element) as an object. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, you would need to add both methods, one as a property that can be used without an element, and one attached to the prototype chain (fn) to be used with elements, but they could both use the same methods and default settings etc. internally, you don't have to write everything twice.